# AngularJS Cannot read property of undefined error

Tags: angularjs

Hello i'm trying to execute a simple function where I multiply 2 integers but i get the Cannot read property of undefined error , here is my code :

```
 $scope.calculTotal= function(id)
   {
     var couttotal=0;
        for (var i=0;i<$scope.ftListe.length;i++)
        {
             for (var j=0;j<$scope.task.length;j++)
              {
                 if($scope.task[j].projet_id==id)
                  { 
                    for(var k=0; k<$scope.lecollaborateur.length; k++)
               {couttotal+=$scope.lecollaborateur[k].cout*$scope.ftListe[i].TempsPasse;}
                  }

              }

        }
        return couttotal;
   };
```

and i get the error : `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'TempsPasse' of undefined"`

Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: Well, is `$scope.ftListe[i]` defined?

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu Yes it is when I console.log($scope.ftListe[i].TempsPasse) I get the result

Comment: Can you post a code snippet or a jsfiddle with the data and this code?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is incorrect:

```
for(var k=0;k<$scope.lecollaborateur.length;i++)
```

Should be

```
for (var k=0; k<$scope.lecollaborateur.length; k++)
```

(it's the 'k' at the end)

Comment: yes sorry about that, that was a mistake i did when copying the code, it's not in the original code so I still have the same issue though

Comment: On your second loop, shouldn't it be looping through scope.ftListe rather than scope.task?

Comment: No actually it's scope.task to access the project_id